# Why do I see an orange star in the tray even when I'm not connected to a VPN?

Tags: windows-7, wireless-networking, vpn, signal-strength

I think I've encountered a bug when connected to Wi-Fi and having a VPN connection set up. Instead of the Wi-Fi signal I see an orange star, even though I am not connected to the VPN:

[image]

And it appears that I am [not the only one](http://www.sevenforums.com/network-sharing/22458-odd-wifi-signal-icon-tray.html).

Is anyone aware of a fix for this?

Comment: There's nothing to be fixed, as soon as your computer receives an ip from the DHCP the "orange star" will disappear..

Comment: But i have IP! Otherwise how i am able to access internet?

Answer (score 0):

You are connected but you don't have any IP address, yet. Check your IP settings, they would be automatic, if so check your DCHP server at where you connected, or assign a static IP to your Wi-Fi connection.

Comment: But i have IP! Otherwise how i am able to access internet?

Comment: "Not available" is the name of the wireless? Hmm... You also connected to RAS. Can you disable it? I hate Vista/7 because they don't show individual network interfaces at the tray like XP does.